# Guys my scrapping tool is constantly returning AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium

please help. I don't understand what is going on here...
I've tried so many different codes and websites and still get the same error all the time.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:/Webdriver/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.dnes.bg/?cat=581')
results =[]
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="lxml")
driver.quit()

for element in soup.findAll(attrs='b2'):
    name = element.find('ttl')
    if name not in results:
        results.append(name).text
print(results)
```

The Error:

Web Scrapper Studio Code\Main.py", line 15, in 
results.append(name).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: what is `results.append().text` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Which elements are _`attrs='b2'`_ elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending to a list returns None

```
a = []
value = a.append("x")
print(value)
None
```

What you probably meant to do is:

```
results.append(name.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. Sayse and undetected Selenium, your questions led me to the problem that I wasn't selecting proper Html resources. And of course thanks jsa for showing me my major mistake.